# Parse JS - how to get list of ACLs user has access to?

Tags: parse-platform

I have used the Parse JS API to setup Roles and Objects
I have secured those Objects with ACLs of the roles
I have attached Users to the Roles in the _Users Relation

... but I can't find any API method in the JS client library's `Parse.User` class to list the  roles that a User is related to.

Am I supposed to approach it the other way round - look through all Roles and filter those that have a relation to my user? I would have thought there was a method on the user object it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will have to create a cloud code functions to search in the roles. Something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('getCurrentUserRoles', ({ user }) => (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role)).equalTo('users', user).find({ useMasterKey: true }));
```